# gcc constant time implemenation

Tags: c, assembly, gcc

I need to make the following function time constant - I have already removed if statements and have written it down to one line in the loop.

```
    /******************/
    uint8_t dseed[54];  // only 0 and 1 like {0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,...}
    uint8_t fecb[256];
    const unsigned char g[55] = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,...};
    /******************/

    memset(fecb,0,54*sizeof(uint8_t));
    for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i--) {
        int feedback = dseed[i] ^ fecb[53];
        for (int j = 53; j > 0; j--){
            fecb[j] = fecb[j - 1] ^ (feedback && g[j]);
        }
        fecb[0] = g[0] && feedback;
    }
```

The code in my eyes looks constant time but when I measure it, it is not. Cycles vary between 165k and 185k.

The assembly code contains a conditional jump.

```
  for (int i = PARAM_K - 1; i >= 0; i--) {               //PARAM_K = 256
  0xC0000556:   C5 04 3F 30  LEA       a4,0xFF
  0xC000055A:   7B 00 00 4C  MOVH      d4,0xC000
> 0xC000059A:   B0 F4        ADD.A     a4,-0x1
> 0xC000059E:   FD 70 47 00  LOOP      a7,0xC000062C  
> 0xC0000622:   B0 F4        ADD.A     a4,-0x1
> 0xC0000626:   FD 70 03 00  LOOP      a7,0xC000062C  
> 0xC000062A:   3C BC        J         0xC00005A2  
> 0xC000062C:   39 AF 37 00  LD.BU     d15,[a10]0x37
> 0xC0000630:   3C A1        J         0xC0000572  
> 0xC0000632:   00 A0        DEBUG     
> 0xC0000634:   3C D0        J         0xC00005D4  

        feedback = dseed[i] ^ fecb[LENGTH - PARAM_K - 1];        //LENGTH = 310
  0xC0000572:   D9 AF 38 00  LEA       a15,[a10]0x38
  0xC0000576:   30 4F        ADD.A     a15,a4
  0xC0000578:   08 05        LD.BU     d5,[a15]0x0
  0xC000057A:   C5 0F 34 00  LEA       a15,0x34
  0xC000057E:   C6 F5        XOR       d5,d15
  0xC0000580:   DA 35        MOV       d15,0x35
  0xC0000582:   DF 05 40 80  JNE       d5,0x0,0xC0000602  <----- JNE
> 0xC00005D4:   82 7F        MOV       d15,0x7                    |
> 0xC00005D6:   C5 0F 35 00  LEA       a15,0x35                   |
                                                                  |
            for (int j = LENGTH - PARAM_K - 1; j > 0; j--)        |
                fecb[j] = fecb[j - 1] ^ (feedback && g[j]);       |
  0xC0000586:   92 F2        ADD       d2,d15,-0x1                |
  0xC0000588:   01 22 00 36  ADDSC.A   a3,a2,d2,0x0               |
  0xC000058C:   14 33        LD.BU     d3,[a3]                    |
  0xC000058E:   10 23        ADDSC.A   a3,a2,d15,0x0              |
  0xC0000590:   02 2F        MOV       d15,d2                     |
  0xC0000592:   34 33        ST.B      [a3],d3                    |
  0xC0000594:   FC F9        LOOP      a15,0xC0000586             |
> 0xC0000602:   60 4E        MOV.A     a14,d4           <---------|
> 0xC0000604:   92 F3        ADD       d3,d15,-0x1                
> 0xC0000606:   10 E6        ADDSC.A   a6,a14,d15,0x0
> 0xC0000608:   01 23 00 56  ADDSC.A   a5,a2,d3,0x0
> 0xC000060C:   10 23        ADDSC.A   a3,a2,d15,0x0
> 0xC000060E:   0C 60        LD.BU     d15,[a6]0x0
> 0xC0000610:   14 52        LD.BU     d2,[a5]
> 0xC0000612:   8B 0F 20 F2  NE        d15,d15,0x0
> 0xC0000616:   C6 2F        XOR       d15,d2
> 0xC0000618:   2C 30        ST.B      [a3]0x0,d15
> 0xC000061A:   02 3F        MOV       d15,d3
> 0xC000061C:   FC F3        LOOP      a15,0xC0000602  

            fecb[0] = g[0] && feedback;
  0xC0000596:   8B 05 20 F2  NE        d15,d5,0x0
> 0xC000059C:   2C A2        ST.B      [a10]0x2,d15
> 0xC000061E:   8B 05 20 F2  NE        d15,d5,0x0
> 0xC0000624:   2C A2        ST.B      [a10]0x2,d15
    }
```

Is this conditional jump responsible for the varying #cycles? ´

I already tried to compile this code snipped using `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))`, and I also tried `volatile int feedback`. Using the volatile keyword, this JNE disappears, but the code still isn't executed in constant time (because of stalls when writing/reading memory maybe?). Cycles vary between 215k and 235k using the volatile keyword.

Can this code efficiently made constant time? Is there some conditional branch I am missing?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will help, but have you tried unrolling the loop?

Comment: no because, the value of "feedback" depends on "fecb" which is assigned in the inner for-loop, so i cannot unroll it right? and it will be 13500 or more lines :/

Comment: Not easily, but not impossible either. If it's really that critical to do optimize it might be worth a try. At the moment, I see a loop in a loop. That won't run in constant time. Take a good look at what constant time would mean. Since `i` is `size(fecb) - 1` and `j` is `size(dseed) - 1`, execution time will be based on those sizes.

Comment: Anyhow, the way your question is phrased, it asks for an explanation of your code. We don't do well with explanations of your code. You wrote it, you should know why it does what it does. If performance of your code is an issue, please describe in some detail what it's supposed to do so we can provide proper feedback on your approach. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: those sizes are fixed.. By constant time I mean, for every input the same execution time. At the moment, the execution time differs depending on the pattern of dseed

Comment: That's probably due to `fecb[j] = fecb[j - 1] ^ (feedback && g[j]);` in the inner loop. `feedback = dseed[i] ^ fecb[53]` after all.

Comment: yes, but that is what I am not getting here. Assembly instruction like XOR etc should perform equally fast no matter what the input pattern looks like, am I wrong? The problem is, I believe, that the compiler somehow wants to shortcut things. But even if I compile with -O0 for no optimization, it is not constant time.

Comment: "Assembly instruction like XOR etc should perform equally fast no matter what the input pattern looks like, am I wrong?" No, this smells like branch prediction.

Comment: I don't know `c` but this line `int feedback = dseed[i] ^ fecb[53];` should throw an indexoutofrange exception.

Comment: What processor/system is this for? Infineon TriCore or something like that? Anyway a time measurement is almost always variable *even if the code is constant time* because of variable measurement errors, which is difficult to eliminate.. though the variation seems large

Comment: How do `NE` and `ST.B` work together? Operator `&&` is not constant time (can skip execution of right side), `&` is (always executes both sides and then combines the result).

Comment: @harold, yes exactly infineon TriCore.

Comment: @firda, thank you!!!!!, I just checked and my code also runs through if using `&` instead of `&&`. then i checked the times - every run takes the same amount of cycles!! If you post an answer, I will accept it! Thank you

Comment: @firda Of-course! Good catch.

Comment: @Mast: I am not sure if I should even post an answer to such questions. It does contain conrete code, it works, nothing theoretical, no more context needed (well, mentioning the processor/architecture could help, but prooved not to be necessary). Got closed, so, maybe I have crossed the line, again.

Comment: @firda Technically, it shouldn't have been answered. But you can give me the blame on this one, I shouldn't have started the comment thread. So don't sweat it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Operator &&](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) is [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which means, that it can give the result based only on the first operand (if it is false, the result is false, no matter what value the second operand has).

[Operator &](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) is not short-circuit and always executes both operands and then combines them.

That appears to be crucial for the code: `feedback && g[j]` and `g[0] && feedback`.

Comment: Note that `feedback && g[j]` and `feedback & g[j]` do not compute to the same value.  A functional equivalent is `!!feedback & !!g[j]` is the same - but may not be time constant.  IAC, unclear what _functionality_ OP wants here.

Comment: @chux: Given the comment `// only 0 and 1 like {0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,...}` and other signs (`fecb[0] = g[0] && feedback;` and `fecb[j] = fecb[j - 1] ^ (feedback && g[j]);`), it was not unreasonable to assume all are indeed ones or zeroes. Anyway, the mixing of binary operators (`^` instead of `!=`) with logical ones (`&&` vs. `&`) is indeed strange as well as the mixture of types (`char`, `uint8_t`, `int`).

Comment: Yes, using only 0 and 1 make `a & b` and `a && b` functionally the same.